# Prevent quotation in window.open in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having a problem with my script. The file wont open if the filename has single quote.

Is there a way to prevent single quote in window.open?

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="window.open('content_files/<?php print($contRow['cont_file']); ?>','<?php print($contRow['cont_file']); ?>','height:auto;width:auto;')">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> View
</a>
```

here's the output

7TATTOOED ON MY MIND CHORDS (ver 2) by D'Sound @ Ultimate-Guitar

Sample Output 1.
[image]

Sample Output 2.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of a "filename with a single quote"?

Comment: Please reread the post. I provide sample output. thanks

Comment: Can you show the result you expected vs the result you got?

Comment: Sample Provided. thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code:

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="window.open('content_files/<?php print(addslashes($contRow['cont_file'])); ?>','<?php print(addslashes($contRow['cont_file'])); ?>','height:auto;width:auto;')">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> View
</a>
```

and It works like a charm. thanks anyway. Credits to the one who deleted he's post but it works.

Comment: Its ok, I had a lot more 'junk' in my post, which was more detrimental in the long run. Glad you got it to work with the basic str_replace (just keep in mind it only covers that single quote, nothing else).

Comment: It's not junk. It doesnt really works. Its saying object not found when I click view

Comment: It's okay with the single quote. because you cant rename a file with special characters like " / \ ? | etc...

Comment: Well, you CAN name a file with all kinds of garbage (except the character for the filesystem's path character; either colon on macos, slash on *nix, or back slash on windows). But all manner others go, heck, some people serve web files with ™, © and even ßqééb in them lol ;) Its better to keep a filename to clean ascii though (not even spaces) when its handled with the web in mind. Which is why I was originally surprised you had files with a single quote in their names (ouch).

Answer (score 1):

You should encode your filename I think:

```
urlencode($contRow['cont_file'])
```

Comment: This SHOULD work... at least in modern browsers like Chrome. I tested it.

Comment: It says Object not found!

Comment: Should I use this before the filename inserted to database? @IncredibleHatdi

Comment: You mean store the encoded filename in the database? No

Comment: @McC0d3 No, when echo'ing it out, you urlencode it: `window.open('content_files/<?php echo urlencode($contRow['cont_file']); ?>' ...` It works well to make the path to the file something the browser won't freak on, and it clears any quoting issues that may break the onclick attribute and inline javascript code. (it should work, although I never tried on bad versions of IE).